# Differentiability of $x^2\times\sin(1/x)$

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

Using first principle, when we try to check the differentiability of $x^2\sin(1/x)$ at $x= 0$,we get 0.
But if we differentiate the function first, and then try to find differentiability at x=0,we we find it's not differentiable.
I have encountered similar questions on stack exchange , but none them gave clarity on which one is right ? Is the function differentiable or not ? Why does the first principle and checking differentiability after differentiating give different answers ?

I know that the derivative of $x^2\sin(1/x)$ is not continuous. Is this the reason why we get different answers ?

Comment: Technically $x^2\sin(1/x)$ is undefined at $x=0$. You can define $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ and set $f(0)=0$ to make $f$ differentiable everywhere, but differentiating $f$ using the formula $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ doesn't tell you what is $f'(0)$ because the formula is not applicable there.

Comment: When you differentiate first, and then compute the limit, you are not finding the differential at 0, but determining if the differential is continuous. So your last sentence is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably, you are talking about the continuous function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2 \sin(1/x) & x \neq 0\\
0 & x = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
As can be shown "using first principle" (by which I assume you mean the definition of the derivative), we find that the derivative of this function is given by
$$
f'(x) = \begin{cases}
2x \sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x) & x \neq 0\\
0 & x = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Because the derivative of $f(x)$ exists at all $x \in \Bbb R$, the function $f(x)$ is indeed differentiable.

This function is unusual, however, in that the derivative $f'(x)$ is not continuous. For a more typical function, we would find that if $f$ is differentiable at $x = 0$, then it would necessarily satisfy $f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0}f'(x)$. As this example illustrates, this does not always need to be the case.

Interestingly, [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) implies that we cannot have a removable discontinuity or jump discontinuity in $f'(x)$. In other words, if $f'(x)$ exists but is discontinuous at $x = 0$, then it **must** be the case that $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f'(x)$ or $\lim_{x \to 0^-}f'(x)$ fails to exist.

Comment: +1 and glad that you added some thing about Darboux theorem and its implications.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a derivative is

$f'(x)=\underset{h\to0}{\text{lim}}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

and that's all there is.  Given $|x^2\sin(1/x)|\le x^2$, it is easily shown (and the OP has apparently done so) that the limit exists and is zero at $x=0$.  The existence and value of the derivative at any given $x$  does not depend on what the derivative might be at other values of $x$.

Whether the derivative is *continuous*, however, does depend on what the derivative is doing is doing at nearby values of $x$.  Here the derivative oscillates wildly for absolutely small, nonzero $x$ so the limit of the derivative fails to exist as $x\to 0$.  So a *continuous* derivative does not exist at $x=0$, but the derivative may still exist as a *discontinuous* function at that point and as we just saw, it does.

All this is assuming a *real* domain only.  If we are working in the *complex* domain, we no longer have $|x^2\sin(1/x)|\le x^2$ and the existence proof no longer works.  We then find an essential singularity at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

By 'checking differentiability after differentiating' I assume you mean differentiating the function on $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ and then letting $x$ goes to zero in $f'(x)$.

As you said, the derivative of a differentiable function is not always continuous so unless it is continuous at $x = 0$, the method does not give anything.

In fact, here, we have for non-zero $x$,

$$
f'(x) = 2x \sin(\frac{1}{x}) - \cos(\frac{1}{x})
$$

and as $x$ converges to zero the first term converges to zero but the second term oscillates faster and faster in $[-1,1]$.

However the limit of $\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0}$ as $x$ converges to zero exists so $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ but the derivative is not continuous at $x=0$.