# To find if a point on the graph is Differentiabe you use the limit defintion of a derivative. But cant we use the power rule instead?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, graph-limits

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkzeZ.png)

In this picture the person determines if the limit exists by checking if the limit from the left is equal to the limit from the right side. But using the power rule instead I just check if the left derivative is equal to the right derivative and if they are equal then the point is differentiable.

Comment: Your technique would imply the derivative is always continuous. This is true often, but there are some dicey examples. So your technique is fine for most normal functions.

Comment: Technically you can't differentiate $x^2$ by power rule to find the (left) derivative at $x=3$ because the formula $x^2$ is only valid for $x < 3,$ not for $x \leq 3.$ If you don't understand why, look carefully at the **definition** of the left derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=a.$ Note that you have to use the function $f(x)$ for the nearby left points **AND** for the base point $x=a.$ In the case of your function, the values of the function at points near but to the left of $x=3$ are computed by using $x^2,$ whereas the value of the function at $x=3$ is computed by using $6x-9$ (i.e. not $x^2).$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Aren't we technically getting the derivative by using the limit definition of a derivative "limit x ->a  f(x)-f(a)/x-a", so basically with the original method we are getting the derivative for 3 using x^2 but instead with the limit definition of a derivative, is my understanding mistaken?

Comment: In what follows, I'll denote the **left derivative** of $f(x)$ at $x=3$ by $f_{-}^{'}(3)$ and the **right derivative** of $f(x)$ at $x=3$ by $f_{+}^{'}(3).$ Note that each of these is a (one-sided) limit of a difference quotient. To show that the derivative exists at $x=3,$ we have to show that the limit of an appropriate difference quotient exists at $x=3,$ which is equivalent to showing that the left limit of the difference quotient at $x=3$ is equal to the right limit of the difference quotient at $x=3,$ **(continued)**

Comment: or (given the earlier definitions of what the left derivative and the right derivative are) we have to show that the left derivative at $x=3$ is equal to the right derivative at $x=3.$ In the case of the left derivative at $x=3,$ we have $f_{-}^{'}(3) = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{-}}\frac{f(x) \, - \, f(3)}{x \, - \, 3} \; = \; \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{-}}\frac{x^2 \, - \, 3^2}{x \, - \, 3} \; = \; \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{-}}\frac{(x-3)(x+3)}{x \, - \, 3} \; = \; \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{-}}(x+3) \; = \; 6.$ **(continued)**

Comment: In the case of the right derivative at $x=3,$ we have $f_{+}^{'}(3) = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{+}}\frac{f(x) \, - \, f(3)}{x \, - \, 3} \; = \; \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{+}}\frac{(6x-9) \, - \, (6\cdot 3 - 9)}{x \, - \, 3} \; = \; \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{+}}\frac{6x \, - \, 18}{x \, - \, 3} \; = \; \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{+}}\frac{6(x \, - \, 3)}{x \, - \, 3} \; = \; \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{+}} 6 \; = \; 6. $ From this we see that each of the one-sided limits exists and their values are the same, **(continued)**

Comment: so the limit itself (i.e. limit of the difference quotient) exists at $x=3,$ which means that the derivative exists at $x=3.$ **An incorrect way is to show** the derivative exists at $x=3$ is to show that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{-}} f'(x) = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{+}} f'(x),$ that is the left limit of the derivative is equal to the right limit of the derivative (i.e. the left limit of a limit of something is equal to the right limit of a limit of something). **(continued)**

Comment: The incorrect way gives $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{-}} (\text{derivative for } x \text{ less than } 3) \; = \; \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{+}} (\text{derivative for } x \text{ greater than } 3),$ which amounts to showing $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{-}} 2x = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{+}} 6,$ and this equality happens to be true, but being true doesn't imply $f_{-}^{'}(x) = f_{+}^{'}(x)$ because it's not what you're supposed to be doing to verify that $f_{-}^{'}(x) = f_{+}^{'}(x)$ is true. **(continued)**

Comment: It's like concluding that $f_{-}^{'}(x) = f_{+}^{'}(x)$ is true by observing that $1 + 1 = 2$ is true. Note that $1 + 1 = 2$ (as is also the case with $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{-}} f'(x) = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3^{+}} f'(x)\,)$ is NOT what you're supposed to be doing to verify that $f_{-}^{'}(x) = f_{+}^{'}(x)$ is true. For an example in which the incorrect way actually leads to an incorrect conclusion, see the MSE question [Differentiability of $x^2\times\sin(1/x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3728673/13130). **(continued)**

Comment: In this case $f'(0)$ exists (in fact, $f'(0)=0),$ but $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^{-}} f'(x)$ does not exist and $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} f'(x)$ does not exist. In this case, if we were trying to determine whether $f'(0)$ exists by checking whether $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^{-}} f'(x) = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} f'(x)$ is true, then we would be lead to the incorrect conclusion that $f'(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for the clarification.