# Differentiabiliy of discontinous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity, piecewise-continuity

I was watching some video about differentiability at some point and I was presented with this function:
$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2}x,\quad  x < 1\\
\sqrt{x}-1 ,\quad x\ge1\\
\end{aligned}
\right.$

And the left hand derivative and right hand derivative, they are both equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ at $x=1$. So that would mean that the derivative exist, but we also know that the function is discontinuous which implies that the function is not differentiable at that point.

So my question is, if we know that differentiabiliy implies continuity,why can't we apply that theorem here. If we tried to find existence of the derivative first at the point $x=1$, which later shows us that left and right side are both equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ then that would imply continuity, but we see the function is discontinuous.

Where is the problem in my logic?

Comment: the left derivative does not exist at $x=1$. It is NOT $\frac{1}{2}$ because what you’re calculating there is $\lim\limits_{t\to 1^-}f’(t)$, which is dffeent from the left-derivative.

Comment: where is your miraculous $\frac{h}{2}$ coming from in the second equal sign? It should be $\frac{1}{2h}+\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. I made such a newbie mistake. So the left derivative would be minus infinity?

Comment: sure if you really want to bring in infinities here (which I suggest you don’t)

Comment: Why do you suggest for that? I was usually showed to evaluate limit like that like it goes to infinity.

Comment: I’m not disagreeing that it is $-\infty$, and of course intuitivity it makes sense as well because the function ‘instantaneously’ jumps from almost $\frac{1}{2}$ down to $0$. All I’m saying is that infinities can be tricky (this particular case isn’t really) so it’s safer to avoid it (until you know the subtleties).

Comment: If one-sided (signed) infinite derivatives are allowed, then at $x=1$ the left derivative is $-\infty$ and the right derivative is $x=\frac{1}{2}.$ The left derivative is easy to see by looking at a rough graph (just sketch it by hand) and drawing in segments from the point $(1,0)$ (which is where the derivatives are evaluated at) to points on the $\frac{1}{2}x$ part of the graph as those latter points approach the point $(1,\frac{1}{2})$ (the point approached by those latter points) -- the segments have negative slopes and approach a vertical orientation in the limit. **(continued)**

Comment: Note that in determining the left derivative at $x=1,$ it doesn't matter how the function is defined for $x>1;$ and in determining the right derivative at $x=1,$ it doesn't matter how the function is defined for $x<1.$ If we change the function so that it's the point $(1,\frac{1}{2})$ that's included (in the definition of the function, change $<$ to $\leq$ and change $\geq$ to $>)$ then at $x=1$ the left derivative will be $\frac{1}{2}$ (or $7,$ if you use $7x$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}x)$ and the right derivative will be $-\infty.$ **(continued)**

Comment: See also my several comments to [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4583743/13130).